# Why Fast Ethernet port in Cisco Packet Service is always down?

Tags: cisco, router

I built a simple network simulation with Cisco Packe Tracer. I am not able to understand why fast ethernet port Fa0/0 on server Gmail and correspondent port on Router2 are always down. I checked and double cheked IP address and everything, but still I am not able to understand what is wrong.

[image: Network image]

I am pretty sure there is a problem with Router2, because I added to the component two PT-ROUTER-NM-1FFE modules for connecting router with two more servers. Checking port status on Router2 I found this:

```
 Router#show ip interface brief
 Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol 
 FastEthernet0/0        172.67.0.1      YES NVRAM  up                    up 
 FastEthernet1/0        151.5.0.1       YES NVRAM  up                    up 
 Serial2/0              152.17.166.2    YES NVRAM  up                    up 
 Serial3/0              unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down 
 FastEthernet4/0        142.251.214.1   YES manual up                    down 
 FastEthernet5/0        153.3.1.1       YES manual up                    down
 Router#
```

As you can see Protocol in FastEthernet4/0 is down, but the port is connected with the right cable (Copper Cross Over), it is on and any other parameter of configuration (band etc) is in auto mode.

[image: port status Router]

Thanks a lot for kindness and helping!

Giancarlo Perlo - Italy

Comment: A status of up/down means a problem with layer 1 or 2.  Remember that packer tracer is not a real router -- it's just a simulator and doesn't always support hardware functions.